# Given $x^3+x-1 = 0$, what's the value of $x^3+2x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Given $x^3+x-1 = 0$, what's the value of $x^3+2x^2$?

obviously $$x^3+2x^2 = 2x^2-x+1$$ but it can't be refactor. Unable to observe anything interesting either.

The numerical solution also doesn't look interesting.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2Bx-1

any other thoughts?

Comment: You mention contest maths, may I know where did you find the question :)

Comment: W|A says that it's 1.2488146599255167259.  That's not going to be 5/4.

Comment: any other attempts ? sticking points? also hopefully not from an active contest.

Comment: Is it given that $x$ is the unique real root of that cubic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the Cardano's formula one can get;
$$x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{31}{27}}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{31}{27}}}$$
By looking at the polynomial $x^3+x-1=0$. We can deduct that;
$$x^2=\frac{1}{x}-1$$
So,
$$x^3+2x^2=x^2(2+x)=(\frac{1}{x}-1)(2+x)=\frac{2}{x}-\left(x+1\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{6}}\left(2\sqrt[3]{36}\left(\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt{\frac{31}{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt{\frac{31}{3}}}\right)^{-1}-\sqrt[3]{6}-\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt{\frac{31}{3}}}-\sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt{\frac{31}{3}}}\right)$$
Or finally;
$$\boxed{x^3+2x^2=-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{18}}\left\{\frac{6\sqrt[3]{12}}{\sqrt[3]{9+\sqrt{93}}+\sqrt[3]{9-\sqrt{93}}}-\left(\sqrt[3]{9+\sqrt{93}}+\sqrt[3]{9-\sqrt{93}}\right)\right\}}$$
I'll edit, If I can find simpler closed form for this.

---

You can also see that;
$$x=\frac{1}{\psi}$$
Where $\psi$ is the [supergolden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergolden_ratio) (The real root of $x^3-x^2-1=0$). Which gives us another hyperbolic equation;
$$x^3+2x^2=\frac{4}{3}\cosh\left(\frac{1}{3}\cosh^{-1}\left(\frac{29}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{3}{1+2\cosh\left(\frac{1}{3}\cosh^{-1}\left(\frac{29}{2}\right)\right)}-\frac{1}{3}$$
And as;
$$\psi=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\sqrt[3]{\frac{29+3\sqrt{93}}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{29-3\sqrt{93}}{2}}\right)_{ }$$
We get the following;

$$x^3+2x^2=\frac{\sqrt[3]{4}}{3}\left(\sqrt[3]{29+3\sqrt{93}}+\sqrt[3]{29-3\sqrt{93}}\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{18}}\left(\sqrt[3]{9+\sqrt{93}}+\sqrt[3]{9-\sqrt{93}}\right)-\frac{1}{3}$$
$$\boxed{x^3+2x^2=\sqrt[3]{\frac{4\left(29+3\sqrt{93}\right)}{27}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{4\left(29-3\sqrt{93}\right)}{27}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{9+\sqrt{93}}{18}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{9-\sqrt{93}}{18}}-\frac{1}{3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Answers to some problems in mathematics are really ugly and probably look uninteresting too. Nobody can help that. If you are looking for something interesting, I can give you the following text. The expression for the only real root of the equation $x^3+x-1=0$ is, 
$$x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\sinh\left(\frac{1}{3}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)=0.68232780382801932736948373971105.$$
Therefore the Wolfram-Alpha is correct. Now, you want to know the value of $x^3+2x^2$. Let,
$$x^3+2x^2=2x^2-x+1=k$$
We can express $k$ as,
$$k=\frac{7+\left(4x-1\right)^2}{8}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$$
$$=\frac{21+\left(8\sinh\left(\frac{1}{3}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)-\sqrt{3}\right)^2}{24} \tag{1}$$
$$=1.2488146599255167259439787107289.\space$$
Once again the Wolfram-Alpha is correct (see the comment from  Matthew Daly).

Now, if (1) does not look interesting enough, then there is nothing else I can do.

Comment: @Mourad Yes, I could have. But I prefer this one. If OP wants it that way, you can post an answer obtained using Cardano-Vieta method.

Comment: well i get your point.